# Scalable ASP.NET hosts for under $20.00/ month

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I am looking for a scalable ASP.NET host for under $20.00/ month.

I need it scalable just in case my website is featured on popular blogs and traffic increases dramatically (in that case, I would increase my budget).

So far I checked Amazon EC2, Rackspace and GoGrid, but they are far too expensive. I also checked GoDaddy 4GH but it limits MSSQL to 200MB.

Comment: Despite the fact that this will probably get closed for being off-topic, I'd like to know the answer.

Comment: @Justin great! keep following it once it gets moved to the appropriate site.

Comment: Scalable how? If your website is featuered on popular blogs or sites it's not going to kill your website, because i highly doubt you will get enough clickthroughs.

Comment: @Phill I agree -I estimate 1% of the blog's daily visits. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Scale, ASP.NET and $20/month is a pretty tough combination. Personally, I would pick a host that offers decent upsizing capabilities -- such as upgrading from shared hosting to a VPS in a pinch -- rather than buying something that claims it will scale for $20 a month.